# Google Map Autocomplete: filter results to contain route city and state

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

Is it possible to get result in the google map autocomplete that must contain route, city and state of United States only.

For example, if i type **New Orleans** then result should display all areas (routes) of New Orleans city only.

Basically i want to bound autocomplete must display name of all routes of specified city. If user just enter"NY" that should pull state name only ideally, then in this case no result should come.

Comment: I think you can do it [Restrict the search to a specific country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete)

Comment: Never Mind, I got the solution. It can be achieved by passing types = 'address'. It pulls all records with route only.